# Change of coordinates matrix, proper subspace

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

I don’t fully understand this exercise and it’s really frustrating.

It says something like this:

> Consider the space $P_2[R]$ with basis:
>
> $B_1 = \{x^2 + x + 1, x, x - 1\}$
>
> $B_2 = \{x^2 - x + 1, x, 2\}$
>
> If $S \in P_2$ is a “proper” subspace and $L_1$ and $L_2$ bases of $S$.
>
> a) Does the change or coordinates matrix from $L_1$ to $B_1$ exist? What would be their size?
>
> b) Does the change or coordinates matrix from $L_1$ to $L_1$ exist? What would be their size?

I did this:

a) If $S$ is a proper subspace of $P_2$ then its basis will have fewer vectors than $P_2$, so $S$ will have one or two basis vectors, right?

I have tried to get the bases of $S$ without success. I tried to write a linear combination. I think that they will be vectors in $P_2$.

I did this:

> $L_1\colon ax^2 + bx + c = \alpha(x^2 + x + 1) + \beta(x) + \delta(x - 1)$
>
> $L_2\colon ax^2 + bx + c = \alpha(x^2 - x + 1) + \beta(x) + \delta(2)$

But I don’t know what to do now. How can I get the bases of $S$ with the given information?

Anyway, I think a) is false because $B_1$ has 3 components, I mean: $\{x^2 + x + 1, x, x - 1\}$ and $S$ is a proper subspace. Then $L_1$ and $L_2$ will have 1 or 2 elements, am I right?

I think b) is true but I’m not sure and I don’t know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*a)Does the change or coordinates matrix from L₁ to B₁ exist?What would be their size?*

It can't exist because $L_1$ has $1$ or $2$ elements whereas $B_1$ has $3$ elements. The matrix of the change of basis should be invertible.

*b)Does the change or coordinates matrix from L₁ to L₁ exist?What would be their size?*

Of course it exist and the size id d-by-d with d dimension of S.

Comment: Thank you for replying, dude!!
How can i get the REAL bases of S with the given information..?

Comment: @JustToKnow It seems we don't have sufficient information for $L_1$ and $L_2$.how are they defined?

Comment: All i know is that they will be vectors in P2. I have a basis for P2; so i think, i can write the basis vectors in L as a linear combination of basis vectors in P2., right?
A friend told me that when I write the basis vectors in L as a linear combination of the basis vectors for the main space P2, the matrix of coefficients gives the transformation into that subspace.
I dont know what to do :(

Comment: we don't have sufficient information, anyway it seems we can answer to both question, are you sure that it is requested to find $L_1$ and $L_2$?